# Not able to Login With Facebook natively

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm able to login in iOS app through Facebook using Browser but if I login in facebook from settings-Facebook then everytime it gives me error. That says

**"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user + ios sdk"**

Please help how I can resolve this.

The error code that I'm getting is this 
Printing description of error:

> Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)" UserInfo=0x10dbf4a90 {com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=400, com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey={
>       body =     {
>           error =         {
>               code = 2500;
>               message = "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.";
>               type = OAuthException;
>           };
>       };
>       code = 400;
>   }}

Comment: what is the error code ?

Answer (score 0):

**An active access token must be used to query information about the current user + ios sdk** 
you are getting this error because you have not logged in through your app.you do not have access-token to communicate with facebook because Facebook sessions and permissions are stored in access tokens, which are cached automatically by the Facebook SDK so they are available when a logged in user returns to your app.
**do you want to integrate facebook login so you should follow folloing url "https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios"**